# Using operator IN with GORM GO / GOLANG

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm trying execute the next query in GORM.

`SELECT * FROM PAINTINGS WHERE in_stock IN (TRUE, FALSE)`

*in_stock is boolean. I know that there are only two types, but i need to filter depending if the user checked two boxes. In this case, user checked first one and NOT the second one.

I found in the documentation (https://gorm.io/docs/query.html conditions / string conditions / IN) a way to do it:

```
GetDB().Where("in_stock IN ?", []bool{true, false}).Find(&paintings)
```

... but it does not retrieve the information. The result shows an empty array.

Is there another way to use 'IN' with GORM?

Additional  info:

GO 1.15.2

DB mysql

Comment: Did you check the query executed in log using `Debug()` ?

Comment: @Eklavya yes, it showed that there was an error with the syntax.

Comment: @luisfa19, was this solved?

Answer (score 2):

I know It's an old question but I've been try the same thing, and I think the best practice would be `Where("in_stock in(?)", []bool{true, false})` instead of `Where("in_stock IN ?", []bool{true, false})`

Another example :

```
func (d *DBAccess) GetRefOrderList(status []int8) (refOrders []models.RefOrders, err error) {

err = d.Table("ref_orders").Where("status in (?)",status).
    Find(&refOrders).Error

return
```

}

Answer (score 0):

So, i found the way to use IN with gorm-GO.

It just need to execute the where without the args as an interface. So i just executed the query interface with the input parameters embedded and deleted the '?'

Here is the code:

```
s := "in_stock IN (true, false)"
GetDB().Where(s).Find(&paintings)
```

*I think is not a good practice, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

```golang
clause.IN{Column: fieldName, Values: values}
```

Ref: https://gorm.io/gen/clause.html

Answer (score 0):

In 2024 the following syntax seems to work.

```
db.Debug().Where("stock IN ?", values).Find(&paintings)
```

Debug() will show you the raw query which will be in the correct SQL syntax "WHERE stock IN (?,?)".

P.S. Remove debug in production.

Answer (score -2):

you can use

GetDB().Where("in_stock IN (?)", []bool{true, false}).Find(&paintings)

Comment: This answer is an unclear duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72631406/14051077